# TypeScript nested objects type definition

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to define the interface Obj to match the objects structure below in the console.log

```ts
interface Obj {
  [key: string]: number or {} // <-------- don't know how to define
}

const returnNestedProp = (obj: Obj) => {
  return obj?.a?.b;
};


console.log(returnNestedProp({ a: 1 }));
console.log(returnNestedProp({ a: { b: { c: 3 } } }));
console.log(returnNestedProp({ b: { a: 1 } }));
console.log(returnNestedProp({ a: { b: 2 } }));
```

in Typescript. don't know hot to define the interface when I have an object or a number. Nested objects

Comment: Your Javascript is inconsistent: you're going to see undefined, {c: 3}, undefined, 2 logged to the console. What is your expected output? Why would you *want* a function where the nesting can have the keys in any order or be arbitrarily deep?

Comment: `[key: string]: number | Obj`   but you will need type guards when accessing the object.  eg.  `if (typeof obj.a === 'number') { /*obj.a is a number*/ } else { /*obj.a is Obj */ }`  etc.

Comment: The compiler won't like `obj?.a?.b` if `obj.a` might be a `number`.  You'd have to jump through hoops to allow that.  Are you okay with refactoring to something like...  the comment that Keith just wrote?

Comment: I suppose you could write `(number & {b?: undefined}) | Obj` instead but that makes me feel unclean.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want a tree type like this:

```
interface Obj {
  [key: string]: number | Obj
}
```

That means that each property of `Obj` may be `number`, or it may be another `Obj`. This allows for tree like nesting to an practically infinite depth.

Then to drill into that, you only need to check if it is `typeof obj.someProp === 'object'`. If that returns true, then Typescript knows that this property is an `Obj` and not a `number`.

```
const returnNestedProp = (obj: Obj) => {
  if (typeof obj.a === 'object') {
    return obj.a.b;
  }
  return
};
```

Test to prove that works:

```
console.log(returnNestedProp({ a: 1 })); // undefined
console.log(returnNestedProp({ a: { b: { c: 3 } } })); // { c: 3 }
console.log(returnNestedProp({ b: { a: 1 } })); // undefined
console.log(returnNestedProp({ a: { b: 2 } })); // 2
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWyDeBYAKGWQG0BrCATwC5kBnMKUAcwF1aQBXAW3WmQA+aLIQC+hQggD2IBsigQwnKCAByEBhAAmABShSADsgC8yABRSstDJgCUJgHy5CxYDHNhKBiFPeXMAHRwJsamAOT+EAhgYfb4RMTyisogyP5BAegA3C7I4gkKSipiOQQSBNKyUgA2EAHVUsxmhSnqmrr6BmY4yHC0AIx5trZZyAD0Y8icIFoQMKDakjJ0NXUNTS0qbZAdht29tD3oh8gItADMeVeiw6MTuKcXeUtVtfWNzclbGjt6e0cnPrIQaiIYjcaTaazeYgRYVZard4bL5qH7aP5dHpAgHIABM11uELxQA)